# How to type Mongo fields that are automatically created in typescript?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is my model, closely following [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/typescript.html) for mongoose v5.13.x with TypeScript:

```
import mongoose, { Model, Schema, Types } from "mongoose";

export interface Foo {
  label: string;

  archived: boolean;
  created_at: number;
  updated_at: number;
}

const FooSchema = new Schema<Foo, Model<Foo>, Foo>(
  {
    label: { type: String },

    archived: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  },
  {
    timestamps: {
      createdAt: "created_at",
      updatedAt: "updated_at",
      currentTime: () => Date.now() / 1000,
    },
  }
);

const Foo: Model<Foo> = mongoose.model<Foo>("Foo", FooSchema);
```

Ok, now I want functions to create and retrieve the model. When I create it, fields that are automatically created like `_id`, `archived`, `created_at`, and `updated_at` should all be optional. But when I retrieve it, they should all be available. For example:

```
type FooInput = {
  label: string;
};

type FooOutput = {
  _id: string;
  label: string;
  archived: boolean;
  created_at: number;
  updated_at: number;
};

export const createFoo = async (foo: FooInput): Promise<FooOutput> => {
  return await Foo.create(foo);
};
```

However, this throws type errors left and right; it'll say `_id` is optional in the output of `Foo.create()`, and if I add it to my type, `Foo.create(foo)` gets upset.

What is the correct way to type fields such as `_id`, `created_at`, etc in this case?

Answer (score 0):

you can make your types extend `mongoose.Document`

Comment: That is recommended against in [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/typescript.html):

"we recommend your document interface not extend Document"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `Model.create()` is a pretty type-unsafe method, so to have decent typing on it I've found I need to declare it myself, along with a `FooInput` type which `Omit`s the fields which can have default values.

I need to create a `TypesafeModel` which overrides `Model`'s `create` and `update` methods, but this doesn't feel great.

```
import mongoose, { Model, Schema, Types, EnforceDocument, FilterQuery } from "mongoose";

interface TypesafeModel<D, I = Partial<D>, QueryHelpers = {}, Methods = {}> extends Omit<Model<D, QueryHelpers, Methods>, 'create' | 'update'> {
  create(doc: I): Promise<EnforceDocument<D, Methods>>,
  update(filter: FilterQuery<D>, doc: Partial<I>): Promise<EnforceDocument<D, Methods>>,
}

export type Foo = {
  _id: Types.ObjectId,
  label: string;
  extra?: string;

  archived: boolean;
  created_at: number;
  updated_at: number;
}

type FooFieldsWithDefaults = '_id' | 'archived' | 'created_at' | 'updated_at'
type FooInput = Omit<Foo, FooFieldsWithDefaults>


interface FooQueryHelpers {}
interface FooMethods {}

interface FooModel extends TypesafeModel<Foo, FooInput, FooQueryHelpers, FooMethods> {
  // statics go here
}

const FooSchema = new Schema<Foo, FooModel, Foo>(
  {
    label: { type: String, required: true },
    extra: { type: String },

    archived: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  },
  {
    timestamps: {
      createdAt: "created_at",
      updatedAt: "updated_at",
      currentTime: () => Date.now() / 1000,
    },
  }
);

const Foo = mongoose.model<Foo, FooModel>("Foo", FooSchema);

export const createFoo = async (foo: FooInput): Promise<Foo> => {
  const good = await Foo.create(foo); 
  const bad = await Foo.create({ wrong: 'stuff' }); // hooray, a type error!
  const bad2 = await Foo.update({'_id': '123'}, { wrong: 'stuff'}); // hooray, a type error!

  return good
};
```